# Dictionary meaning required

Tags: mandarin, meaning

On my Chinese dictionary, there are a few characters that I don't know what it means. It says: 商务印书馆. I want to know what it means.

Comment: This could easily have been looked up in a dictionary, like CC-EDICT, freely available.

Comment: I don't find that in my dictionary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick [Google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%E5%95%86%E5%8A%A1%E5%8D%B0%E4%B9%A6%E9%A6%86&biw=1093&bih=545&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=wi7lVPSNIsj0oAS8-YD4Bg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAA&dpr=1.25) search told me this:

商务印书馆 is the first modern publishing organization in China.

Your dictionary is probably published by 商务印书馆.

[image: pic]

Comment: Modern?? 商务印书馆The Commercial Press, Beijing (est. 1897)

Comment: @Pedroski That sounds modern to me.

Comment: Maybe you would like to change your name to Methuselah!笑话啊！

Answer (score 2):

It's the name of the publisher of the dictionary. Xin Hua Zi Dian (新华字典) by 商务印书馆(literally: Commercial Press/Publishing/Printing Company) is the standard dictionary or at least the recommended dictionary by education ministry for schoolers in Mainland China. It's like what Webster dictionary is in the U.S. or Oxford dictionary is in the U.K.